# List of integer unmarshalling incorrectly

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

My code was working fine for a while. I changed some things, and now I have some lists of integers which are not unmarshalling correctly anymore. To try and weed out the problem, I have boiled the entire thing down to the following and the problem still persists.

I have reduced my XML file down to a test file for which the entire contents is

```
<polylist>
    <p>1 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 2 3 1 3 1 1 4 2 1 5</p>
</polylist>
```

I have reduced my Java code down to a test file for which the entire contents is

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "polylist")
public class PolyList
{
    public List<Integer> p;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(PolyList.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        PolyList pl = (PolyList)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("ptest.xml"));
        System.out.println(pl.p);
    }
}
```

Printing pl.p results in an output of `[1291596391]` which is not the `[1 0 0 0 0 1 2 ...]` that was expected. If I change `public List<Integer> p;` to `public List<String> p;` then it correctly outputs `[1 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 2 3 1 3 1 1 4 2 1 5]` as expected. So it correctly aquires a `List<String>` but not a `List<Integer>`. It was working fine, correctly getting a `List<Integer>` a few days ago in the full production project, but not anymore.

(edit)
Actually, the `List<String>` version is NOT working either. There are no commas between the numbers, meaning that it is not showing a list of multiple strings, each string representing a different number. Rather, it is still 1 String representing the whole thing.

Thank you, Blaise, for pointing that out. My mistake for not noticing it sooner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `@XmlList` annotation on the `p` field.

```
@XmlList
public List<Integer> p;
```

---

**UPDATE**

The following is true, I would have to investigate further as to why.

```
javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseInt("1 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 2 3 1 3 1 1 4 2 1 5") == 1291596391
```

> If I change public List p; to public List p; then it
>   correctly outputs [1 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 2 3 1 3 1 1 4 2 1 5] as expected.

If you change it to `List<String>` you will get a `List` with one entry that is `1 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 2 3 1 3 1 1 4 2 1 5`.  With the `@XmlList` annotation you will get output of `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 5]` indicating that it is a `List` with many items.

Comment: Why does it seem to work sometimes without XmlList but sometimes it does not work and requires it? Or perhaps a better question: if it works without the XmlList annotation, is that technically incorrect behavior which I should not be counting on and therefore always include the annotation in this situation?

Comment: @Loduwijk - I can't envision a way that this would sometimes work.  The  only two ways to convert space separated items to a `List` is to either use `@XmlList` or `@XmlValue` on a `List` property.

Comment: Oh oops! I didn't even realize that the String version did not have commas, which would indeed mean that it too was a list with 1 element. My mistake. Still, since it worked before, according to what you are saying it must have had the XmlList annotation if it was working properly. I will just assume that I had the XmlList and deleted it at some time in the recent past. I do not know why I would have done that, and I do not recall doing it, but I will just assume that I must have.